# How can I upload changed files to a website in Linux?

Tags: linux, ftp, web

I maintain the website for my daughter's school. Historically I used our service provider's webftp interface to make edits in-place through their web-based GUI, which worked well for the small edits I typically need to make. They recently disabled webftp for security reasons, leaving ftp as the means to modify web pages and upload documents. Yes, I know FTP isn't very secure itself, but that's another story.

I have used wget to pull down the site and have built a git repository to manage changes. As I make changes, I want to upload the new and modified files to the website. Ideally I would only upload the new and changed files, not the entire site. My question is how do I do this?

I have found wput, which looks promising, but its documentation is not clear about which directory that wget created is the one I should recursively upload, and what the target directory should be. Since we are talking about a live site, I don't want to experiment until I get things right.

This seems like it should be a common use case with a well-known solution, but I have had little luck finding one. I have tried searches on Google and Stack Overflow with terms like "upload changed files ftp linux", but no clear answer pops up like I usually get. Some recommend rsync, but the target is on the service provider's system, so that might not work. Many variants of my question that I have found are Windows-centric and of little help since I work on Linux.

I suppose I could set up a target VM and experiment with that, but that seems excessive for what should be an easily answered question, hence my appeal to Stack Overflow. What do you recommend?

Comment: Have you thought of getting the remote site with a recursive get, then using a recursive diff against the current local and new locally copied directory to obtain a list of files that need uploading?

Comment: I used wget to recursively transfer the site to my workstation, and a recursive file comparison that triggers an upload in the case of difference is exactly what I am looking for. I'd rather have it all work automatically than to generate an upload list that needs to be further processed. Yes, it could be easily handled by a script, but surely such a thing already exists. I am just having trouble finding it.

Comment: I tried wput and while it certainly recursively uploads files, it always seems to upload them, even if they have not changed. I tried various combinations of --timestamping --reupload and --dont-continue but it always uploaded the files. I turned on --verbose mode, which said that since the files were text, it ignored file size as a criterion for uploading and always uploads. I then turned on --binary, but it still uploaded the files. Perhaps it just can't parse the timestamp field. The support page on wput's SourceForge site shows no closed issues since 2008, so I think wput is abandoned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this answer helps you : https://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp/24833#24833

It uses [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/)'s mirror function to sync up a remote and local directory tree.

I also used mc's ([midnight commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/)) built in ftp client quite a lot when maintaining a site.

Comment: Thanks @jpjacobs. The lftp program did the trick. The command `lftp -c mirror -Re localdir ftp://username:password@ftp.website.com/remotedir` is exactly what I needed--a reverse mirror with remote file deletion when they disappear locally. I was able to create a test directory tree parallel to the main site's directory so I could test safely.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [git](http://git-scm.com/) with [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp). It is generally a good idea to use a VCS by any project...